# Xcode firebase error user info NSlocalizedDescripion query cancelled

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase

I created a user interface in my story board  where you can

sign into my app after you put in your sign in info you

click on my create account buttons and your data is saved

into firebase. When I click on the create account button I

receive an error message instead of the data going into

firebase .below this paragraph is the error message I

receive in my xcode console.

xc2018-08-12 22:29:44.542313-0400 Moments1[5892:185726]

[BoringSSL] Function boringssl_context_get_peer_sct_list: line

1754 received sct extension length is less than sct data length

2018-08-12 22:29:44.703683-0400 Moments1[5892:185719] TIC Read

Status [1:0x0]: 1:572018-08-12 22:29:44.703928-0400

Moments1[5892:185719] TIC Read Status [1:0x0]: 1:57

2018-08-12 22:29:44.531385-0400 Moments1[5892:185725] 5.0.0 -

[Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023007] Firebase Analytics v.50000000

started2018-08-12 22:29:44.784178-0400 Moments1[5892:185725]

5.0.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023008] To enable debug logging

set the following application argument: -FIRAnalyticsDebugEnabled

(see)2018-08-12 22:29:44.976416-0400 Moments1[5892:185719] 5.0.0

- [Firebase/Database][I-RDB038012] Listener at /media failed:

permission_denied2018-08-12 22:29:46.151902-0400

Moments1[5892:185472] [MC] Lazy loading NSBundle

MobileCoreServices.framework

2018-08-12 22:29:46.153620-0400 Moments1[5892:185472] [MC] Loaded

MobileCoreServices.framework

2018-08-12 22:29:46.162144-0400 Moments1[5892:185472] [MC] System

group container for systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles

pathis/Users/reginaldaugustin/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Dev

ices/0EF9772C-248B-4AE8-A5CC-

D29284F71437/data/Containers/Shared/SystemGroup/systemgroup.com.a

pple.configurationprofiles

2018-08-12 22:29:46.219849-0400 Moments1[5892:185472]

[LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.

Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is

one you don't want.

Try this:

(1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't

expect;

```
(2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or
```

constraints and fix it.

(

"

UIImageView:0x7fc5f06173c0.height == 19   (active)>",

"

[UIImageView:0x7fc5f06173c0]   (active, names:

'|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fc5f0616eb0 )>",

"

[UIImageView:0x7fc5f06173c0]-(12)-|   (active, names:

'|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fc5f0616eb0 )>",

"

Height' UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fc5f0616eb0.height ==

43.6667   (active)>"

)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint

UIImageView:0x7fc5f06173c0.height == 19   (active)>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at

UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the

debugger.

The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on

UIView listed in  may also be helpful.

2018-08-12 22:29:46.230628-0400 Moments1[5892:185472]

[LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.

```
Probably at least one of the constraints in the following
```

list is one you don't want.

Try this:

(1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't

expect;

(2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or

constraints and fix it.

(

"

UIImageView:0x7fc5f0553ff0.height == 19   (active)>",

"

[UIImageView:0x7fc5f0553ff0]   (active, names:

'|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fc5f0553bf0 )>",

"

[UIImageView:0x7fc5f0553ff0]-(12)-|   (active, names:

'|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fc5f0553bf0 )>",

"

Height' UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fc5f0553bf0.height ==

43.6667   (active)>"

)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint

UIImageView:0x7fc5f0553ff0.height == 19   (active)>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at

UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the

debugger.

The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on

UIView listed in  may also be helpful.

2018-08-12 22:29:46.239446-0400 Moments1[5892:185472]

[LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.

Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is

one you don't want.

Try this:

```
(1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you
```

don't expect;

(2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or

constraints and fix it.

(

"

UIImageView:0x7fc5f0557950.height == 19   (active)>",

"

[UIImageView:0x7fc5f0557950]-(12)-|   (active, names:

'|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fc5f0557760 )>",

"

[UIImageView:0x7fc5f0557950]   (active, names:

'|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fc5f0557760 )>",

"

Layout-Height' UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fc5f0557760.height =

= 43.6667   (active)>"

)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint

UIImageView:0x7fc5f0557950.height == 19   (active)>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at

UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the

debugger.

The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on

UIView listed in  may also be helpful.

2018-08-12 22:29:46.248280-0400 Moments1[5892:185472] [

LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following lis

t is one you don't want.

```
Try this: 







(1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you
```

don't expect;

```
(2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or
```

constraints and fix it.

(

"

UIImageView:0x7fc5f05598e0.height == 19   (active)>",

"

[UIImageView:0x7fc5f05598e0]-(12)-|   (active, names:

'|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fc5f05596f0 )>",

"

[UIImageView:0x7fc5f05598e0]   (active, names:

'|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fc5f05596f0 )>",

"

Height' UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fc5f05596f0.height ==

43.6667   (active)>"

)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint

UIImageView:0x7fc5f05598e0.height == 19   (active)>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at

UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the

debugger.

The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on

UIView listed in  may also be helpful.

2018-08-12 22:29:49.989331-0400 Moments1[5892:185472] [MC]

Reading from private effective user settings.

2018-08-12 22:29:54.496034-0400 Moments1[5892:185726] [discovery]

errors encountered while discovering extensions: Error

Domain=PlugInKit Code=13 "query cancelled" UserInfo=

{NSLocalizedDescription=query cancelled}

2018-08-12 22:29:44.542313-0400 Moments1[5892:185726] [BoringSSL]

Function boringssl_context_get_peer_sct_list: line 1754 received

sct extension length is less than sct data length

2018-08-12 22:29:44.703683-0400 Moments1[5892:185719] TIC Read

Status [1:0x0]: 1:57

2018-08-12 22:29:44.703928-0400 Moments1[5892:185719] TIC Read

Status [1:0x0]: 1:57

2018-08-12 22:29:44.531385-0400 Moments1[5892:185725] 5.0.0 -

[Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023007] Firebase Analytics v.50000000

started

2018-08-12 22:29:44.784178-0400 Moments1[5892:185725] 5.0.0 -

[Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023008] To enable debug logging set the

following application argument: -FIRAnalyticsDebugEnabled (see)

2018-08-12 22:29:44.976416-0400 Moments1[5892:185719] 5.0.0 -

[Firebase/Database][I-RDB038012] Listener at /media failed:

permission_denied

2018-08-12 22:29:46.151902-0400 Moments1[5892:185472] [MC] Lazy

loading NSBundle MobileCoreServices.framework

2018-08-12 22:29:46.153620-0400 Moments1[5892:185472] [MC] Loaded

MobileCoreServices.framework

2018-08-12 22:29:46.162144-0400 Moments1[5892:185472] [MC] System

group container for systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles

path is

/Users/reginaldaugustin/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/0

EF9772C-248B-4AE8-A5CC-

D29284F71437/data/Containers/Shared/SystemGroup/systemgroup.com.a

pple.configurationprofiles

2018-08-12 22:29:46.219849-0400 Moments1[5892:185472]

[LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.

```
Probably at least one of the constraints in the following
```

list is one you don't want.

Try this:

(1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't

expect;

(2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or

constraints and fix it.

(

"

UIImageView:0x7fc5f06173c0.height == 19   (active)>",

"

[UIImageView:0x7fc5f06173c0]   (active, names:

'|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fc5f0616eb0 )>",

```
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60400028f230 V:
```

[UIImageView:0x7fc5f06173c0]-(12)-|   (active, names:

'|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fc5f0616eb0 )>",

"

Layout-Height' UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fc5f0616eb0.height

== 43.6667   (active)>"

)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint

UIImageView:0x7fc5f06173c0.height == 19   (active)>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at

UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the

debugger.

The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on

UIView listed in  may also be helpful.

2018-08-12 22:29:46.230628-0400 Moments1[5892:185472]

[LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.

Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is

one you don't want.

Try this:

(1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't

expect;

```
(2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or
```

constraints and fix it.

(

"

UIImageView:0x7fc5f0553ff0.height == 19   (active)>",

"

[UIImageView:0x7fc5f0553ff0]   (active, names: '

|

':UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fc5f0553bf0 )>",

"

[UIImageView:0x7fc5f0553ff0]-(12)-|   (active, names:

'|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fc5f0553bf0 )>",

"

Layout-Height' UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fc5f0553bf0.height

== 43.6667   (active)>"

)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint

UIImageView:0x7fc5f0553ff0.height == 19   (active)>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at

UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the

debugger.

The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on

UIView listed in  may also be helpful.

2018-08-12 22:29:46.239446-0400 Moments1[5892:185472]

[LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.

Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is

one you don't want.

Try this:

```
    (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which
```

you don't expect;

```
(2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or
```

constraints and fix it.

(

"

UIImageView:0x7fc5f0557950.height == 19   (active)>",

"

[UIImageView:0x7fc5f0557950]-(12)-|   (active, names: '

|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fc5f0557760 )>",

```
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6040002901d0 V:|-(12)-
```

[UIImageView:0x7fc5f0557950]   (active, names:

'|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fc5f0557760 )>",

"

Height' UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fc5f0557760.height ==

43.6667   (active)>"

)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint

UIImageView:0x7fc5f0557950.height == 19   (active)>

Make a symbolic breakpoint

UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the

debugger.

The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on

UIView listed in  may also be helpful.

2018-08-12 22:29:46.248280-0400 Moments1[5892:185472]

[LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.

```
Probably at least one of the constraints in the following
```

list is one you don't want.

Try this:

```
(1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you
```

don't expect;

```
(2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or
```

constraints and fix it.

(

"

UIImageView:0x7fc5f05598e0.height == 19   (active)>",

"

[UIImageView:0x7fc5f05598e0]-(12)-|   (active, names:

'

|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fc5f05596f0 )>",

"

[UIImageView:0x7fc5f05598e0]   (active, names:

'|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fc5f05596f0 )>",

"

Layout-Height' UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fc5f05596f0.height

== 43.6667   (active)>"

)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint

UIImageView:0x7fc5f05598e0.height == 19   (active)>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at

UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the

debugger.

The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in  may also be helpful.

2018-08-12 22:29:49.989331-0400 Moments1[5892:185472] Reading

from private effective user settings2018-08-12 22:29:54.496034-

0400 Moments1[5892:185726] [discovery] errors encountered while

discovering extensions: Error Domain=PlugInKit Code=13 "query

.cancelled" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=query cancelled}

Comment: You really need to edit your question, it is completely unreadable right now...

Comment: At first I thought it's some kind of a strange poem...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a lot of things going on here and there looks like there are a lot of unrelated constraint errors but it seems like you are using Firebase Realtime Database and you are getting a permission denied error. This probably means that your security rules are not what you expect them to be. One problem that I recently ran into was that the Firebase console now defaults its UI to the Firebase Firestore database instead of the realtime database and I was making changes the the Firestore rules instead of the Realtime Database rules. You can toggle between the databases here:

[image: firebase console]

Comment: I enabled the real time database in firebase and i entered my login info and tried to click on the create new account button to upload my data to firebase  but  i am receiving the same error in the console. The data also did not go to the realtime database in the firebase project.

Comment: it works turns out in the authentication i needed to enable the email and password option and save it . the project works now